# SwiftUI/AppWindowsController.swift:89: Fatal error

Tags: macos, swiftui

Has anyone seen this error before?

`SwiftUI/AppWindowsController.swift:89: Fatal error`

Looked across Google and couldn't find much on it. I'm trying to develop a simple menu bar app for macos and running into this error whenever I try to run my app. I'm thinking it could be a bug with AppStorage but I'm not sure. I have also set the Boolean key Application is agent (UI Element) to 'YES' within my Info.plist file. This key specifies the following as per [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256):

> LSUIElement (Boolean - macOS) specifies whether the app runs as an agent app. If this key is set to YES, Launch Services runs the app as an agent app. Agent apps do not appear in the Dock or in the Force Quit window. Although they typically run as background apps, they can come to the foreground to present a user interface if desired. A click on a window belonging to an agent app brings that app forward to handle events.

I'm also wondering if this key is causing my app to crash with the error, but I have toggled the value to `YES` and `NO`, and the app crashes with either value set.

I'm running Xcode 15.2 with Swift 5.9.2. The minimum deployment version is macOS 14.2.

Here is my full application code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct GiveMeTwentyApp: App {
    
    @AppStorage(SettingsKeys.showAppInMenuBar) var showAppInMenuBar: Bool = true
    
    var body: some Scene {
        #if os(macOS)
        MenuBarExtra(isInserted: $showAppInMenuBar) {
            ContentView()
                .navigationTitle("GiveMeTwenty")
        } label: {
            Label("GiveMeTwenty", systemImage: "star")
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
        #endif
        
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .navigationTitle("GiveMeTwenty")
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
import Foundation

enum SettingsKeys {
    static let reminderFrequency = "reminderFrequency"
    static let runWhenComputerStarts = "runWhenComputerStarts"
    static let showAppInMenuBar = "showAppInMenuBar"
    static let popUpMenuMessage = "popUpMenuMessage"
    static let notificationsEnabled = "notificationsEnabled"
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // Configure app to send reminders every x hours
    @AppStorage(SettingsKeys.reminderFrequency) var reminderFrequency: Int = 1
    
    // Configure app to send notifications or not
    @AppStorage(SettingsKeys.notificationsEnabled) var notificationsEnabled: Bool = true
    
    // Configure app to run when computer starts
    @AppStorage(SettingsKeys.runWhenComputerStarts) var runWhenComputerStarts: Bool = true
    
    // Configure app to appear in menu bar or not
    @AppStorage(SettingsKeys.showAppInMenuBar) var showAppInMenuBar: Bool = true
    
    // Configure message to show on popUp Menu
    @AppStorage(SettingsKeys.popUpMenuMessage) var popUpMenuMessage: String = "Give Me Twenty!"
    
    private let reminderFrequencyOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Picker("Every", selection: $reminderFrequency) {
                    ForEach(reminderFrequencyOptions, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0.description)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 80)
                .clipped()
                
                Text("hours take a break.")
                
            }
            .padding()
            
            Toggle(isOn: $notificationsEnabled) {
                Text("Enable notifications")
            }
            .toggleStyle(.checkbox)
            .padding()
            
            Toggle(isOn: $runWhenComputerStarts) {
                Text("Run when computer starts")
            }
            .toggleStyle(.checkbox)
            .padding()
            
            Toggle(isOn: $showAppInMenuBar) {
                Text("Show app in menu bar")
            }
            .toggleStyle(.checkbox)
            .padding()
            
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove these lines:

```
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .navigationTitle("GiveMeTwenty")
        }
```

because you only want the UI to appear when the user taps the menubar icon.

Note that it's not a problem with this `WindowGroup` *per se*, because if you comment out the `MenuBarExtra` block, it *also* works, but not as a menubar-only app.

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you.  I was under the impression that, that WindowGroup was required as a default case, for when the if statement's condition was not met.

Comment: You can put it in an `#else` clause, but since this is a macOS-only app, you don't need to.